# Connecting to Oracle DB from .NET/C#

Tags: c#, oracle

After finding [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18692/Instant-Oracle-Using-C), I downloaded and extracted the files needed. But when I try to add their reference I get this error message:

> A Reference to '..\oci.dll' could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.

Any help with this?

Comment: I think you would need `Oracle.DataAccess` fine print it says *Once you have these files, simply copy them into the same directory as your executable*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should download and install ODP.NET (Oracle Data Provider for .NET)

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html

For deployment look at the http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-nov/o68odpnet-101744.html, but basically is xcopy deployment as V4Vendetta noted

Update: Client application need these dll's (32 bit version):

```
oci.dll 
Oracle.DataAccess.dll 
oraociei11.dll 
OraOps11w.dll
```

Comment: Okey, ive downloaded the data provider. but i need to distribute my little program, is telling me right now that its missing Oracle.DataAccess. Any hot tips on what dlls that are needed?